# NEON suffix support in Android Studio cmake project

Tags: android, cmake, arm, simd, neon

According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpu-arm-neon.html?hl=zh-cn#uns), we can require the compiler to compile sources files with NEON support:

```
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c.neon bar.c
```

But how to do this with cmake? In Android Studio, cmake doesn't recognize *.neon* suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no neon suffix.
Either you write your NEON codes in inline assembly or intrinsics in you c/cpp file, then compile it.